# A question on uniformly accelerated motion

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

In my book on uniformly accelerated motion there is the following exercise:

*A body, initially stationary, moves with constant acceleration and travels $20$ m in $5$ s.
What space does it travel in $20$ s*?

A:$1600\, m.$

B:$320\, m.$

C:$400\, m.$

D: cannot be answered because the acceleration
of the motion.

---

The book's answer is **B**.

**My attempts**: If I apply the formula $$x=x_0+\left(\frac{v+v_0}{2}\right)t \tag 1$$
I obtain $v=\frac{20 m}{5 s}= 4\frac ms$ and $\Delta x=x-x_0=\left(\frac{v+v_0}{2}\right)t=40 m$ and it not possible. If I do a proportion

$$20 m : 5 s = x: 20 s \implies x=80 \,m$$
but this not is the solution. How should one proceed because I don't have any additional information? The question is taken from a second-year high school physics textbook.

Comment: After I would like to understand the reason for the closure (+1) to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start from rest and move with constant acceleration $a$ which gives us $$\frac{dv}{dt}=a\implies v = at + v_0\implies v=at$$ because our initial speed is zero.

We now have $$\frac{dx}{dt}=at\implies x=\frac{1}{2}at^2+x_0$$ and since we are allowed to choose our starting position we take $x_0=0$ to get $$x=\frac{1}{2}at^2$$

We are told we travel $20$m in $5$ seconds which gives us $$\frac{1}{2}a(5)^2=20\implies a=\frac{8}{5}$$ meters per second squared. Plugging $a$ back into our equation of motion we get $$x=\frac{4}{5}t^2$$

Therefore, $x(20)=\frac{4}{5}(400)=320$

Comment: One can even be simpler here and not compute the unknown acceleration: $x$ varies is directly proportional to $t^2$, so a 4-fold increase in time yields a 16-fold increase in distance.

Comment: @Semiclassical How is that simpler? You have to know that that constant acceleration means directly proportional to the square of time. I believe that is only intuitive after you have learned basic physics.

Comment: You need to know $x=\frac12 a t^2$. But from there the fact that $x\propto t^2$ is immediate, hence $x_2=(t_2/t_1)^2x_1=16x_1$ (as in JMP's answer). Calculating the actual value of $a$ can thus be bypassed. (In this problem it's not a big deal, but in problems with additional constants it's important to be able to avoid unnecessary calculations.)

Comment: I gladly accept your answer and thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 4):

Using $x=\frac{1}{2}at^2$ and given $x_1=20,t_1=5,t_2=20$, we can say

$x_1=\frac{1}{2}at_1^2$, and so $a=\frac{2x_1}{t_1^2}$

Then $x_2=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x_1}{t_1^2}t_2^2=x_1\frac{t_2^2}{t_1^2}=x_1\left(\frac{t_2}{t_1}\right)^2=20\cdot16=320$.

Comment: The acceleration is $1.6$ meters per second squared. Your solution works because $x=\frac{1}{2}at^2$.

Comment: @JohnDouma; well you multiply by $2$ and then divide by $2$ in the next step!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Peraphs I have understood.

$$x-x_0=\left(\frac{v+v_0}{2}\right)t \iff \frac{2(x-x_0)}{t}=v \tag 2$$
being $v_0=0$.
Then

$$\frac{2\cdot 20m}{5}=v=8 m/s$$

$$a=\frac{8m/s}{5s}=1.6 m/s^2$$

$$v=at=1.6\cdot 20=32 m/s$$

$$\Delta x=\frac 12 a t^2=.5\cdot 1.6 \cdot 400=320 m.$$